# Presto - split the array by certain value

Tags: arrays, presto

I want to split the array by a certain value. Here, Say 1

I tried using "transform", but couldn't progress, and "split" is useful with strings.

```
Input : [1,8,2,1,4,5,6,1,1,4,2,4,1]

Expected Output : [[1,8,2],[1,4,5,6],[1],[1,4,2,4],[1]]
```

Comment: Did you try `reduce` (https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#reduce)?

Comment: What's the expected output if the input does not start with 1?

Comment: @MartinTraverso leave out the part till 1, and then to get what's needed

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but you can do it using [`reduce`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#reduce):

```sql
WITH t(a) AS (VALUES
    array[1,8,2,1,4,5,6,1,1,4,2,4,1],
    array[8,2,1,4,5,6,1,1,4,2,4,1]
)

SELECT
    reduce(
        a,
        array[array[-1]],
        (state, value) -> case
            when value = 1 then
                concat(state, array[value])
            else
                concat(slice(state, 1, cardinality(state) - 1), array[concat(slice(state, -1, 1)[1], array[value])])
            end,
            state -> slice(state, 2, cardinality(state) - 1)
        )
FROM t
```

The idea is to use an array as state value, which will contain all the groups derived so far. It's initialized with a single group containing an arbitrary value (`array[array[-1]]`) to get around an ambiguity during type inference. That group is discarded when the results are produced (`array[array[-1]]`).

As each element in the input array is processed, if it's a `1`, a new group is added to the state (`concat(state, array[value])`). Otherwise, the value is added to the last group derived so far (`concat(slice(state, 1, cardinality(state) - 1), array[concat(slice(state, -1, 1)[1], array[value])])`).